# Is there a way to scan HTML across a site and get a list of classnames?

Tags: html, css

I want to know all the class names (other attributes would be fine too) that occur within a site. I am approaching a major refactor of a front-end and inherited code that is not very modular. I'm particularly interested in class names being used, and where they are used, and some type of grouping would be helpful.

Comment: [This question is off-topic (#4)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @zzzzBov Why cleaning your code would be off topic ?

Comment: @bokan, read the link. I don't know how it could possibly be clearer.

Comment: @zzzzBov : Quote : "if your question is about :
- software tools commonly used by programmers;
- and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"
This question fall in both categories. I don't how this could possibly be clearer too.

Comment: @bokan, If you'd ***actually read the link***, you'd know it says: "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**... 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @zzzzBov I think you're too picky and strict. The problem mavame is raising is a very common problem that all caring web developers encounter. And this question with a good answer (I hope better than mine) would be a good ressource here. I really don't think this particular topic is prone for spam or opinionated answers as they are barely no solutions available. Maybe we could just make this question better instead of kiling it. I just edited the tilte and remove the query for a "tool".

Answer (score -2):

There are several tools for this.

One is the [dust-me plugin for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/). Activate it, browse all the pages of your website, it will tell you what is not used.